# Ultisnips - Create a placeholder/tabstop inside a python interpolation?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

It's possible to create a placeholder inside a python interpolation block?.

I want to do a snippet for my grammar exercises.
I'm currently in this snippet.

```
snippet "ej(ercicio)?( (\d+))?" "Ejercicios - grammar" br
${1:unidad}.${2:ejercicio} )$0`!p
num = match.group(3) if match.group(2) is not None else 2
for var in range(2, int(num)+1):
→   snip += str(var) + " -> $"+str(var + 1)`

endsnippet
```

But it outputs

```
ej 8<tab>

unidad.ejercicio )¬
2 -> $3¬
3 -> $4¬
4 -> $5¬
5 -> $6¬
6 -> $7¬
7 -> $8¬
8 -> $9¬
```

(the first it's always an example, so i don't print it)

Any clue?

Comment: It can be done, but in a rather roundabout way. Have a look at this [dynamic tabstop generation example](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/examples/tabstop-generation/README.md)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to husB for point me the [dynamic tabstop generation](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/examples/tabstop-generation/README.md), i don't know why it isn't in the doc.

The final snippet:

```
global !p
def create_line_plhldr(snip):

    num = int(snip.buffer[snip.line].strip())

    snip.buffer[snip.line] = ''

    anon_snippet_body = '${1:unidad}.${2:ejercicio} )'
    for var in range(2, int(num)+1):
        anon_snippet_body += '\n' + str(var) + " -> $"+str(var + 1)

    snip.expand_anon(anon_snippet_body)
endglobal

post_jump "create_line_plhldr(snip)"
snippet "ej(ercicio)?( (\d+))?" "Ejercicios - grammar" br
`!p snip.rv = match.group(3) if match.group(2) is not None else 2 `
endsnippet
```